# GRUB no longer shows Windows 10 in dual boot menu during Windows update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, grub2, windows-10

I've had Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16 dual booting without any problems for several months.

Normally it auto boots to Ubuntu, but if I hit esc on the first boot screen, I go into the dual boot menu of Grub where it lets me pick Windows.

Just now however, I was in Windows 10 and decided to finally 'update and restart' to install the updates that it had been bothering me about for a while, but I had resisted installing.

This required multiple restarts. 15% installed, restart, I hit esc on boot to go into Grub and select Windows. 30% installed, restart, however this time I noticed that the Windows option had been moved from position 1 in the boot menu to position 3. 50-60% installed, and this time when it restarted, I'm no longer seeing Windows as an option in the dual boot menu.

Any ideas?

I have a SSD and a normal HD, Windows came pre-installed on the SSD and I installed Ubuntu on the HD.

EDIT: After another restart, Windows appears in the Grub menu again.

Comment: Are you able to still boot into Ubuntu? If not, you've probably been hit by the notorious Microsoft `Windows 10 Anniversary Update` bug. If unsure, boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD and take a screenshot of your /dev/sda and edit your question with the image, and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the Windows Update overwrote GRUB, but the absence of the boot menu suggests so.

I would try booting into the Ubuntu Live USB and running boot-repair to reinstall GRUB. After booting into the live USB, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then this should appear, and click "Recommended repair"

[image]